# m2eclipse: add group id to project name when importing existing maven project into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

in Eclipse I use file -> import -> existing maven project to create Eclipse-projects for existing Maven projects. Unfortunately the names of the created Eclipse projects equals the name of the Maven-projects and do not contain the group id.
For the maven goal eclipse:eclipse you can set the parameter "addGroupIdToProjectName". How can I set this parameter for the project creation by m2eclipse?

Thanks for answers,
Timk

Answer (score 10, accepted):

up to now I could not find any possibility to set the name for the Eclipse-projects to [groupId].[artifactId] globally. But you can set it every time you import existing Maven projects into eclipse: In the import-dialog open the "advanced" options and set the "name template" to "[groupId].[artifactId]".

Tomka.